# Prove by induction, for all positive integers $n$, that $n!\ge2^{n-1}$

Tags: inequality, induction

So far I have:
**Base case:** $n=1$: LHS: $1!=1$, RHS: $2^{1-1}=1$, $1\ge1$ so $P(1)$ is true.
**Inductive step:** Assume $n=k$ is true, that is $k!\ge2^{k-1}$, we must show that $n=k+1$ is true, that is $(k+1)!\ge2^k$.
$(k+1)!=k!(k+1)\ge2^{k-1}(k+1)$ (since we assume $k!\ge2^{k-1}$)

Not really sure what to do after this, I know that $2^{k-1}=$$2^k\over2$ but I don't know if that helps at all.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: you just finsh since $2^{k-1}\times (k+1) \geq 2^{k-1}\times2 = 2^k$ hence you prooved that $(k+1)! \geq 2^{k}$

Answer (score -1):

Since $k+1\geqslant2$, $2^{k-1}(k+1)\geqslant2^{k-1}\times2=2^k$,